# Get results by finding an ID which is two joins away using Eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to get rows from one table using an id which is two joins away.
I know I can use `join('table_name')` but I am trying to use the model names rather than raw table names.

I'm trying to select `shipping_shipment.*` by joining `order_item_join_shipping_shipment` then joining `order_item`, and filtering `where order_item.order_id = x`

I tried this in the ShippingShipment class, but I can't figure it out.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderItem::class, ShippingShipment::class, 'shipment_id', 'order_item_id', 'id', 'id');
```

There are many items in an order, and many shipments. I need to get the shipments.
There can be more than one shipment per order - items come from various places.
There can be more than one shipment per item - if something is returned and needs shipping again.

The table I want to get rows from, shipping_shipment, is joined to order_item by a join table order_item_join_shipping_shipment. That join table has the order_item_id. I need then to join order_item table so that I can search for order_item.order_id

Table **order_item** model OrderItem

```
+-----+---------------+
| id  | order_id      |
+-----+---------------+
|  6  |     13464     |
|  8  |     13464     |
|  9  |     13464     |
+-----+---------------+
```

Table **order_item_join_shipping_shipment** model OrderItemJoinShippingShipment

```
+-----+---------------+-------------+
| id  | order_item_id | shipment_id |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  1  |       6       |     12      |
|  1  |       9       |     12      | two items in one shipment
|     |               |             |
|  2  |       8       |     13      |
|  3  |       8       |     14      | one item was returned so shipped again
+-----+---------------+-------------+
```

Table **shipping_shipment** don't need describing except to say it has an id column.

If I was to do it with MySQL it would look like this

```
SELECT ss.*, oiss.order_item_id FROM 
    order_item_join_shipping_shipment AS oiss
    INNER JOIN shipping_shipment AS ss ON (oiss.shipment_id = ss.id)
    INNER JOIN order_item AS oi ON (oiss.order_item_id = oi.id)
WHERE oi.order_id = 13464
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are not using the [default table names](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names), so your Models must have the table names explicit, e.g.:

```
class OrderItem extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'order_item';
}
```

In the same Model file of the above example, you need to indicate how the relationship works, i.e.:

```
public function shippingShipments()
{
 
    return $this->belongsToMany(ShippingShipment::class, 'order_item_join_shipping_shipment', 'order_item_id', 'shipment_id');

}
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) you can check in Laravel documentation the whole explanation.

You need to apply the same concept in ShippingShipment Model, so your Model will be something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'order_item';
    

    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function orderItens()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OrderItem::class, 'order_item_join_shipping_shipment', 'shipment_id', 'order_item_id');

    }
}
```

This way you can get shipments by order item and vice-versa:

```
//Shipments of Order item 13464
$shipments = OrderItem::find(13464)->shippingShipments()->get();

//Order items of Shipment 1
$orders = ShippingShipment::find(1)->orderItems()->get();
```

Source: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks. I think that's closer but I need to search order_id not order_item.id. It needs to also join the order_items table. I can get close by calling `$OrderItem->shippingShipments()->where('order_id', '=', $id)->get();` but it returns `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id' `

Comment: If you created the relation between order Model and order items Model, you can use a foreach loop like `foreach (Order::find(13464)->orderItems()->get() as $orderItem)` to bring a collection of order items. Then, you can get shipments `$orderItem->shippingShipments()->get()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are using a pivot table between ShippingShipment and OrderItem. If I understand you correctly you want to get OrderItems that are connected to ShippingShipment, if that is the case this is what you can do:

Make belongs to many relationships in both models, such as:

> ShippingShipment:

```
public function orderItems(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(OrderItem::class, 'table_name', 'column_id');
}
```

> OrderItem:

```
public function shippingShipment(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(ShippingShipment::class, 'table_name', 'column_id');
}
```

And then you can get the desired result by typing this query:

```
 ShippingShipment::find(1)->with('orderItems')->get();

OrderItem::find(13464)->with('shippingShipments')->get();
```

Note: you can use ***orderItems:id,order*** or ***shippingShipment:id,some_other_field*** for more optimized query